# Getting Action link text from another action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a MVC Controller with a action which returns a string. I want my Action link to have this returned string as name. Can any one suggest how to do this in my view? I have written the markup code in my view which I thought might be able to do the trick but I guess I am wrong.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
string returnedstr = @Html.Action("_MessagePartial", "UserMessage");
@Html.ActionLink(returnedstr, "Index", "UserMessage")
}
```

Comment: `Html.Action` returns the RESULT of that action as a string. Why would you want that as the `ActionLink` text?

Comment: It counts the number of unread notification for the user and return a summary like "1 msg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a MVC Controller with a action which returns a string.

That's a problem. In ASP.NET MVC controller actions return ActionResults, not strings. That's why the Html.Action helper doesn't do what you think it does.

> I want my Action link to have this returned string as name.

You could use a custom helper instead of a controller action that will return the desired string:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static string GetName(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        // do something and ...
        return "some name";
    }
}
```

and in your view:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(Html.GetName(), "Index", "UserMessage")
}
```

Or just make this a property on your view model:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(Model.SomeName, "Index", "UserMessage")
}
```

and then have the controller action that is serving this view simply populate the corresponding property on the view model.